# Is this construction correct? "Today is [(pro)noun] [gerund]"

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-order, gerunds, construction

"Today is [(pro)noun] [gerund]"

Context: Some time ago, my friend and I were messaging each other and then I used this construction. He immediately said that my sentence should've been "Today [(pro)noun] is [present participle]". I replied saying that that construction changes the meaning I originally intended. I said that "Today" should be the subject, not the adverb. Then there was a back and forth of arguments. I then made up an instance in restaurant where there will be a guest singer. A manager says "Today is Madonna singing". That didn't work either. I then told him to think of it like a list (yesterday was x x-ing, today is x x-ing, tomorrow will be x x-ing). I told him to also think of "Madonna singing" as a noun phrase, not noun + verb. He asked some of his friends too and none of them have heard of this construction.

So, is this construction something that exists or is it something I made up? I don't think I made it up because I have a definite feeling I picked it up from somewhere and I have kept it because I think it's correct.

Edit 1: Another example I thought of is "Tomorrow will be him doing it" (which seems correct to me).

Edit 2: Thanks to everyone that answered! (I am not going to put the tick mark on anyone because many people helped; putting it on only one person would be unfair).

Comment: In *Today is Madonna singing*, the verb (*is*) sets up an equivalence. Another example would be *Madonna is a singer**. That latter makes sense, but *today* is a day and *Madonna singing* is an activity. There's no equivalence, so your sentence makes no sense. You may mean *Today Madonna is singing*. Now the verb is *is singing*, which describes the activity that Madonna is doing.

Comment: Well, can't "Today is Madonna singing" be considered a contraction of "Today is the day of Madonna singing"  or something else?

Comment: It's certainly not a contraction, which would require an apostrophe to indicate the missing letters. Idiomatically, you'd say *Today is the day that Madonna sings*. Your version runs into the wall of English sentence construction that has "Subject Copulative-Verb Predicate-Complement*. Hard to climb over that.

Comment: “Tomorrow will be him doing it” and “Today is Madonna singing” can possibly work if you set up a very, very specific context—but as general sentences with no further context, they are meaningless and don't make sense.

Comment: @deadrat I didn't literally mean contractions in that sense. Oh well, thanks for answering.

Comment: These are sentence fragments. But they're even more problematic than more common ones ('_Please!_' / 'On the table.'  / ...) 'Sentence' can be used as an attributive as they _can_ convey a complete thought (but they're not sentences, hence 'fragment/s). As others have stated, context governs acceptability; "Today is Madonna singing." is fine in informal conversation after say "There are quite a few things I want to see on TV this week –". "Today[,] it's Madonna singing." and "Today ...  Madonna singing." are alternatives. But in isolation and/or in formal communication, inappropriate.

Comment: "Today is Madonna singing" is OK. "Madonna singing" is a noun phrase as subject complement of "be" in its specifying sense. "Madonna" is head of the NP, and "singing" is a non-finite clause modifying "Madonna". (cf. "Today is Madonna who is singing ...")

Comment: Your examples are not good English, but people do talk that way, if that helps to know.

Answer (score 2):

A way to look at your question is to consider that the gerund functions as a noun (or a noun group).

*Today is [Madonna singing]* => *Today is [the day when Madonna is singing]*

Said otherwise, *Madonna's concert is today*. I do not see any particular violations in your turn of phrase. It's a matter of taste and ultimately your freedom to express yourself as you see fit, within the grammatical boundaries of the language.